# install4j: Using environment variable for file chooser default

Tags: install4j

I am adding a file chooser on a form and I want to default the initial directory to be an environment variable. If I specify it as ${MY_ENV_VARB}, I don't see it being populated (install4j version 5.1.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables are not supported in text field expressions, you would have to add a "Set a variable" action with a "Variable name" of "myVar" and a script of

```
System.getenv("MY_VAR")
```

and then use it with the syntax

```
${installer:myVar}
```